# Advise that submit events on forms does not work on code snippets

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-snippets

Code snippets in posts are executed on `<iframe>` in sandbox mode; with the follow permissions: `sandbox="allow-modals allow-scripts"`. The option `allow-forms` is not added probably due to security concerns; this for sure it's a good idea.

The thing is that today I come across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/1218618), which relies on a code snippet sample which use `submit` event to work, and of course it's blocked when it runs in Chrome; and in this case the example in the answer fails showing the correspondent error in the console:

```
Blocked form submission to '' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.
```

I simple edit the question to bind the validate function to the click event on button instead of a `<form>`, so no problem at all, but my concern is:

Could be a good idea when a submit form is detected in a code snippet to advise the user that this not will work?

Comment: Sigh. The answer is using a regex to validate an email address, and you are complaining about the implementation of the example. Don't miss the forest for the trees.

Comment: @CodyGray maybe there are better examples to illustrate the problem... but I think that the forest is the `allow-forms` permissions despiste the example.

Comment: Maybe it's the nature of the users of snippets, but wouldn't one maybe want to ... test the code they post?

Comment: @CodeCaster yup... totally agree, probably your comment is the correct answer for my question :)

Comment: Using JS to process forms with `preventDefault()` seems to work in Firefox (v50) but not in Chrome (v55).  See, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/28324083. Is there a good reason why?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say no, don't implement this.

My reasoning: there are many things that don't work in a sandboxed iframe, so the development team will have to keep adding checks. Good static analysis that catches these cases is also not trivially implemented.

So: leave it up to the user who posts a snippet (or converts existing code into a snippet) to test whether their code works in the sandboxed iframe.

Comment: In the mentioned answer the code was "broken" by a reviewer who adds the code snippet not by the OP,  but I'm agree the solution is not trivial implemented and finally as you comment the solution is as easy as test the code you post.

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not sure why you're telling me this. I'm just giving my opinion, I'm not a developer with Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: _No, don't implement this_ and _the development team_  so I assumed you were

Comment: @mplungjan alright, I can understand the confusion. Maybe add your own answer to add why you _would_ like to see it implemented! :)

Answer (score 3):

I would say "Yes, please implement this"

## AND THEY LISTENED

Why can't you allow a submit? I run into this on at least a weekly basis. 
I am not bothered by any other restrictions

Within one hour today

- [Jquery dialog with submit function on select-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139836/jquery-dialog-with-submit-function-on-select-box)
- [Reloading of deleted list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138655/reloading-of-deleted-list-items)

Downvoted and closed meta question:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337476/allow-submitting-a-form-inside-a-stack-snippet referring to
[How to lanuch a post using javascript or jquery when I click a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437981/how-to-lanuch-a-post-using-javascript-or-jquery-when-i-click-a-button/40438062#40438062)

I have many times had to add a jsfiddle.net to overcome this issue.

UPDATE: Within one hour today too:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42340273/295783

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42338272/295783

Comment: Good point; what happen when the OP problem involves a submit button? then the example could not work as a code snippet. My question was not well focused to explain this case.