# Why is form submit disabled in stack snippets?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

Some questions require an answer with a submit in it.

As I explain in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339535/295783, 
I daily run into not being able to post a snippet in an answer that has a form submission in it.

It is not enough to [Advise that submit events on forms does not work on code snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339479/advise-that-submit-events-on-forms-does-not-work-on-code-snippets)

Also [Add allow-modals to the sandbox of Stack Snippets, snippets are broken in Chrome 46+](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297048/add-allow-modals-to-the-sandbox-of-stack-snippets-snippets-are-broken-in-chrome) is only discussing alerts, prompts and confirms

I have not found any good explanation for this sandbox setting.

> As usual, please don't just downvote - let me know WHY you do not agree on me asking to relax the sandbox.

Comment: *Perhaps we can have some kind of setting to allow submissions that can be toggled by us who know what we are doing?* How do you envision that system to work?  If you just use rep then would I be able to submit a form that has a security hole because I have never used it before?  I just can't see how you would tell the people who should be allowed from the people who should not be allowed.

Comment: Ok, Removed the suggestion. Then please explain me then WHY the submit is disabled.

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think it was disabled, more like not enabled after browser updates disabled it by default. now it's enabled. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just added the `allow-forms` token to the snippet's [`iframe's sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) attribute, so submission is now possible:

```html
<form action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Since we already allow your arbitrary script, allowing form submission didn't seem to add any new capabilities that would cause more security concerns.